# Odoo Qweb generated pdf report shows overlapping of the address and table rows of 2nd page

Tags: pdf, report, odoo, wkhtmltopdf, invoice

When generating an invoice there is overlapping where the customer address should be and in cases where the invoice is more than one page, the table header and rows write over each other. Using the latest Odoo system and have already updated the WKHTMLTOPDF library to the latest stable release, 0.12.2.1

Answer (score 2):

## This is the correct Solution for overlapping between table row and table header in multi page PDF

### Adding the following in the CSS fixes

thead { display: table-header-group }
   tfoot { display: table-row-group }
   tr { page-break-inside: avoid } or style="page-break-inside: avoid;"

Answer (score 0):

That version of wkhtmltopdf gave me problems as well, its layouts are pretty bad. I'm using the version 0.12.1 right now and everything works fine. Try to downgrade the library to that version. I think it will help to solve your problems :)

Answer (score 0):

**0.12.2.1 is the wrong version.**

> Danger
>
> to print PDF reports, you must install wkhtmltopdf yourself: the
>   version of wkhtmltopdf available in debian repositories does not
>   support headers and footers so it can not be installed automatically.
>   The recommended version is 0.12.1 and is available on the wkhtmltopdf
>   download page, in the archive section. As there is no official release
>   for Debian Jessie, you can find ours on
>   http://nightly.odoo.com/extra/.

From

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html#deb