# How to display table header in all page in qweb report odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb, odoo-11

I have one Qweb report which has table 
it contains table header and table data 
now issue is in multiple page report.
if any char or text field has long text  it overlaps with header.
see below images of both pages of report.

[first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjcYC.png)

[second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lojVt.png)

My Table Code is:

```
<table  class="table table-bordered" width="100%" >
                                <thead >
                                    <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
                                        <td class="text-left">Code</td>
                                        <td class="text-left">Description</td>
                                        <td class="text-left">U/M</td>
                                        <td class="text-right">QTY</td>
                                        <td class="text-right">RATE</td>


                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
                                <tr  t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
                                    <td><span t-field="l.product_id.default_code"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="l.name"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="l.uom_id.name"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="l.quantity"/></td>
                                    <td><span t-field="l.price_unit"/></td>                         
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                     <td class="text-left" colspan="5">
                                        <b>GRAND TOTAL AED : </b>
                                     </td>
                                     <td class="text-left" colspan="2">
                                        <b>
                                            <t t-set="total" t-value="0"/>
                                                <t t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="f">
                                                    <t t-set="total" t-value="total+f.price_subtotal"/>
                                                    <t t-if="f_last">
                                                        <strong>
                                                        <t t-esc="total"/>
                                                        </strong>
                                                </t>
                                            </t>
                                        </b>
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                            <b><span t-field="o.amount_tax"/></b>
                                     </td>
                                     <td >
                                            <b>
                                            <t t-set="total" t-value="0"/>
                                                <t t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="f">
                                                    <t t-set="total" t-value="total+f.price_total"/>
                                                    <t t-if="f_last">
                                                        <strong>
                                                        <t t-esc="total"/>
                                                        </strong>
                                                </t>
                                            </t>
                                        </b>
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Please post your code!!!... Also try to set a paper format for that report and adjust the header space.

Comment: added my table design code
i have tried paperformat but not working

Comment: This answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722977/odoo-qweb-generated-pdf-report-shows-overlapping-of-the-address-and-table-rows-o

Answer (score 0):

Error can be slove by two ways

1) Go to Settings -> Reports Paper Format -> create a Paper Format duplication of European A4 and modify
`Header Spacing`    : `40`
`Associated Reports` : "Report Name"

2) Other by code in xml

```
<!-------------Create Paper Format------------------------>
<record id="report_paperformat_id" model="report.paperformat">
        <field name="name">Test</field>
        <field name="default" eval="True" />
        <field name="format">A4</field>
        <field name="page_height">0</field>
        <field name="page_width">0</field>
        <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
        <field name="margin_top">42</field>
        <field name="margin_bottom">23</field>
        <field name="margin_left">7</field>
        <field name="margin_right">7</field>
        <field name="header_line" eval="False" />
        <field name="header_spacing">40</field>
        <field name="dpi">90</field>
 </record>

<!---set paper format to Report -->
<record id="report_module.report" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
        <field name="paperformat_id" ref="report_module.report_paperformat_id" />
</record>
```

Comment: Hi Deval
i have tried of paperformat but not succeed

Comment: Hi @jacksparrow include more header spacing it will help you

Comment: yes its affecting but not overlaping text whole table is moving

Comment: Did you included table in header ?