# Odoo invoice page break after 30 lines

Tags: odoo, qweb

I created a custom invoice but now I am having trouble breaking the page when product lines are more than 30. I am trying to do this so it doesn't overlap with the total amount and payment terms ([see image for the desired scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlarW.png))

Update code snippet:
https://pastebin.com/WDr5uphK

I tried adding `<div style="page-break-after: always;"/>` using `foreach` but it breaks the whole table and moves to next page.

Comment: You can add a condition in `t-foreach` to close the `t-body` and `table`, add the `div` then open a new `table` and `t-body`.

Comment: @Kenly thank you for the response. can you please share a snippet? it will be really helpful for me to implement that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close the table, add the page break and open a new table

***Example:***

```
<t t-if="page_break == row_index">
  &lt;/tbody&gt;
  &lt;/table&gt;

  <div style="dislay: block;page-break-after: always;"/>

  &lt;table class="table"&gt;
  &lt;tbody&gt;
</t>
```

Comment: Hi, updated my code but then it creates a new page after every row. https://pastebin.com/WDr5uphK

Comment: In my example above I used the `row` variable in `foreach` so I can use `row_index` and `page_break` is set on the form view (`Integer` field). In your example, you used the `line` variable and want to break after ``30`` lines so the condition should be: `<t t-if="line_index == 30">`

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. However, when it breaks and goes to the new page, the header hides some of the lines (around 5-6 lines are missing). https://i.imgur.com/BpOJIbx.png

Comment: Try to change `margin_top` and/or `header_spacing` in paper format and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722977/odoo-qweb-generated-pdf-report-shows-overlapping-of-the-address-and-table-rows-o

Comment: Thank you, `margin_top` did the job! But the payment terms and the total amount show only on the first page. Is it possible to show it on all pages (same location) or only on the last page?

Comment: You can use [report_qweb_element_page_visibility](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/14.0/report_qweb_element_page_visibility) module to show it on the last page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250140/discussion-between-hassan-yousuf-and-kenly).

Answer (score 0):

if `<tfoot>` doesn't work you could add a last `<tr>` in the end outside the loop:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="pl_custom_invoice_report.report_invoice_document_carbon">
  <div class="article" t-att-data-oe-model="o and o._name" t-att-data-oe-id="o and o.id" t-att-data-oe-lang="o and o.env.context.get('lang')">
    <t t-raw="0"/>
    <t t-call="pl_custom_invoice_report.custom_invoice_header_footer"/>
    <div style="padding-top:180px;"></div>
    <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context(lang=lang)"/>
    <div class="page" style="position:relative !important;">
      <t t-set="display_discount" t-value="any([l.discount for l in o.invoice_line_ids])"/>

      <table class="table table-sm table-borderless o_main_table" style="border-bottom:4px solid white;margin-bottom:50px;">
        <tbody class="invoice_tbody" style="font-size: 14px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
          <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0"/>
          <t t-set="lines" t-value="o.invoice_line_ids.sorted(key=lambda l: (-l.sequence, l.date, l.move_name, -l.id), reverse=True)"/>
          <t t-set="sequence" t-value="1"/>

          <t t-foreach="lines" t-as="line" style="border: 0 solid">

            <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="current_subtotal + line.price_subtotal" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_excluded"/>
            <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="current_subtotal + line.price_total" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_included"/>

            <tr t-att-class="'bg-200 font-weight-bold o_line_section' if line.display_type == 'line_section' else 'font-italic o_line_note' if line.display_type == 'line_note' else ''" style="padding: 0; margin:0; font-size:14px">
              <t t-if="not line.display_type" name="account_invoice_line_accountable" style="padding: 0; margin:0; font-size:14px;">

                <td name="account_invoice_line_sequence" style="padding: 0; margin:0;text-align:center;font-size:14px;">
                  <span t-esc="sequence"/>
                </td>
                <td name="account_invoice_line_name" style="padding: 0; margin:0 0 0 0 !important;">
                  <span style="margin-left:30px;" t-field="line.name" t-options="{'widget': 'text'}"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right" style="padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 80 !important; font-size:14px;">
                  <t t-if="line.product_uom_id.name == 'Units'">
                    <t t-esc=" '%.0f' % line.quantity"/>
                  </t>

                  <t t-if="line.product_uom_id.name == 'kg'">
                    <t t-esc=" '%.3f' % line.quantity"/>
                  </t>

                  <span style="margin-right:50px; text-transform:lowercase;" t-field="line.product_uom_id" groups="uom.group_uom"/>
                </td>

                <td t-attf-class="text-left {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}" style="padding: 0; float:right; margin:0;">
                  <span style="margin-right:50px; float:left;" class="text-nowrap" t-field="line.price_unit"/>
                </td>
                <td t-if="display_discount" t-attf-class="text-right {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}" style="padding: 0; margin:0;">
                  <span class="text-nowrap" t-field="line.discount"/>
                </td>
                <td t-attf-class="text-left {{ 'd-none d-md-table-cell' if report_type == 'html' else '' }}" style="padding: 0; margin:0;">
                  <span t-esc="', '.join(map(lambda x: (x.description or x.name), line.tax_ids))" id="line_tax_ids"/>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right o_price_total" style="padding: 0; margin: 0 20 0 0;">
                  <span class="text-nowrap" t-field="line.price_subtotal" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_excluded"/>
                  <span class="text-nowrap" t-field="line.price_total" groups="account.group_show_line_subtotals_tax_included"/>
                </td>
              </t>
              <t t-if="line.display_type == 'line_section'">
                <td colspan="99">
                  <span t-field="line.name" t-options="{'widget': 'text'}"/>
                </td>
                <t t-set="current_section" t-value="line"/>
                <t t-set="current_subtotal" t-value="0"/>
              </t>
              <t t-if="line.display_type == 'line_note'">
                <td colspan="99">
                  <span t-field="line.name" t-options="{'widget': 'text'}"/>
                </td>
              </t>
            </tr>
            <t t-if="current_section and (line_last or lines[line_index+1].display_type == 'line_section')">
              <tr class="is-subtotal text-right">
                <td colspan="99">
                  <strong class="mr16">Subtotal</strong>
                  <span t-esc="current_subtotal" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;monetary&quot;, &quot;display_currency&quot;: o.currency_id}"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </t>
            <t t-set="sequence" t-value="sequence + 1"/>
          </t>


<!-- STARTS HERE -->


          <tr>
            <td colspan="99">
              <div class="clearfix" style="position:absolute !important; top: 710px; right: 250px;line-height:0">
                    <!--<p t-if="o.narration" name="comment">
                                        <span t-field="o.narration"/>
                                    </p>-->
                    <p t-if="o.invoice_payment_term_id" name="payment_term" style="font-size:12px;margin-left:-120px;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:0">
                                    Payment <b>
                    <span t-field="o.invoice_payment_term_id"/>
                    </b> after statement of accounts
                                                            <!--<span t-field="o.invoice_payment_term_id.note"/>-->
                </p>
                <p t-if="o.amount_total" style="font-size:12px;margin-left:-120px;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:normal">
                    <span t-esc="o.compute_amount_in_word(o.amount_total)"/>
                </p>

                <div id="total" class="row" style="margin-top:-30px !important;">
                    <div t-attf-class="#{'col-6' if report_type != 'html' else 'col-sm-7 col-md-6'} ml-auto">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-borderless" style="page-break-inside: avoid; width:222px; margin-left:235px !important;border-bottom: 4px solid white">
                        <tr>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <strong>TOTAL</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td style="" class="text-right">
                            <span class="text-nowrap text-right" style="" t-field="o.amount_total"/>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

<!-- ENDS HERE -->


        </tbody>
        

      </table>

      
    </div>

    <p t-if="o.fiscal_position_id.note" name="note">
      <span t-field="o.fiscal_position_id.note"/>
    </p>
    <div id="qrcode" t-if="(o.company_id.qr_code) and (o.currency_id.name == 'EUR') and (o.invoice_partner_bank_id.acc_number != False)">
      <p t-if="(o.invoice_partner_bank_id.qr_code_valid)">
        <strong class="text-center">Scan me with your banking app.</strong>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <img class="border border-dark rounded" t-att-src="o.invoice_partner_bank_id.build_qr_code_url(o.amount_residual, o.invoice_payment_ref or o.ref or o.name)"/>
      </p>
      <p t-if="(o.invoice_partner_bank_id.qr_code_valid == False)">
        <strong class="text-center">The SEPA QR Code informations are not set correctly.</strong>
        <br/>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--            </t>-->
</t>
```

Comment: Hi, I did this but the result is the same. https://imgur.com/a/uGytezC

Comment: hi I did follow the updated snippet but it had no effect.